# Generating dictionary does not always work

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, random

I am trying to generate a dictionary automatically with a for loop (i < numero_usuarios), the keys are taken from a list with names, and the values are randomly generated with a random.randint(1, 10), the problem is that it does not always generate the amount I want.

For instance, I want to create 10 users(usuarios), it sometimes creates 7, 8 or 9, but rarely 10.

Code below.

```
import random

class practica6:

#Create our constructor
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        # Initialize users dictionary
        self.usuarios = {}
        #List of possible names the users can take
        self.nombres = ['Mario', 'Pepe', 'Angel', 'Joaquin', 'Jesus', 'Edson', 'Emilio', 
        'Eli', 'Francisco', 'Sergio', 
        'Erick', 'David', 'Liam', 'Noah', 'Oliver', 'William', 'James', 'Benjamin', 'Lucas', 
        'Henry', 'Alexander', 
        'Mason', 'Michael', 'Ethan', 'Mateo', 'Sebastian', 'Jack', 'Peter', 'Josh', 
        'Patricia', 'Luis', 'Gerardo', 'Carmen']


    def generar_diccionario_usuarios(self, numero_usuarios : int):
        #Generate a dictionary with random names (keys) and random priority (values) keys : 
        #values
        for i in range(numero_usuarios):
            self.usuarios[random.choice(self.nombres)] = random.randint(1, 10)
        #DEBUG : Print our users dictionary
        print(self.usuarios)

#Test app
practica = practica6()
n = 10
print('Usuarios:')
practica.generar_diccionario_usuarios(n)
```

Comment: Are you saying you are worried that _it's not generating the integer value 10 often enough?_ It just did for me, twice `'{Alexander': 3, 'Jack': 1, 'Erick': 10, 'David': 10, 'Carmen': 7}`. This is just how random numbers work...

Comment: I'm a bit unclear. You say "I want to create 10 users(usuarios)" but your loop is controlled by `numero_usuarios` which you have set at 5 wouldn't this always create 5 users? (Actually it might produces less if  `random.choice` chooses a name twice, which would overwrite the previous value is that the issue you're referring to?)

Comment: No, I am saying It does not create 10 users, or the number I want. If I use a small number "n" like 5, it creates the five users, but if I want to increase it to >10 It just does not work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a dictionary, a key cannot appear multiple times, and all attempts to insert a key which exists already will result in overwriting the stored value.
`random.choice`, being a draw **with** replacement, can return the same user **multiple times**. You need to use `random.sample`, which simulates a draw **without** replacement:

```
for nombre in random.sample(self.nombres, numero_usuarios):
    self.usuarios[nombre] = random.randint(1, 10)
```

Comment: Indeed!, thank you for your answer. I think its the simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you get duplicate keys in your dict when choosing one randomly at a time.

You could generate a list of `numero_usarios` distinct keys with

```
distinct_names = random.sample(self.nombres, k=numero_usarios)
```

and a list of random integers with

```
values = random.choices(range(1, 11), k=numero_usarios)
```

Then you can build the dict by pairing these lists with

```
self.usuarios =  dict(zip(distinct_names, values))
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that sometimes the "random.choice(self.nombres)" generates the same name so it overights,
so the solution is :

```py
import random
class practica6:

#Create our constructor
   def __init__(self) -> None:
       # Initialize users dictionary
       self.usuarios = {}
       #List of possible names the users can take
       self.nombres = ['Mario', 'Pepe', 'Angel', 'Joaquin', 'Jesus', 'Edson', 'Emilio', 
       'Eli', 'Francisco', 'Sergio', 
       'Erick', 'David', 'Liam', 'Noah', 'Oliver', 'William', 'James', 'Benjamin', 'Lucas', 
       'Henry', 'Alexander', 
       'Mason', 'Michael', 'Ethan', 'Mateo', 'Sebastian', 'Jack', 'Peter', 'Josh', 
       'Patricia', 'Luis', 'Gerardo', 'Carmen']


   def generar_diccionario_usuarios(self, numero_usuarios : int):
       #Generate a dictionary with random names (keys) and random priority (values) keys : 
       #values
       for i in range(numero_usuarios):
           name = random.choice(self.nombres)
           while name in self.usuarios.keys():
               name = random.choice(self.nombres)
           self.usuarios[name] = random.randint(1, 10)
       #DEBUG : Print our users dictionary
       print(self.usuarios)

#Test app
practica = practica6()
n = 10
print('Usuarios:')
practica.generar_diccionario_usuarios(n)
```

thank you, hope it wokrs cuz it worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that sometimes, when picking a random name- that name could already be in the dict.  Why not randomise the names from the start, and as they are added to the dict, remove them from the list?

```
import random

class Practica6:

    def __init__(self) -> object:
        # Initialize users dictionary
        self.usuarios = {}
        #List of possible names the users can take- shuffled
        self.nombres = random.shuffle(['Mario', 'Pepe', 'Angel', 'Joaquin', 'Jesus', 'Edson', 'Emilio', 
        'Eli', 'Francisco', 'Sergio', 
        'Erick', 'David', 'Liam', 'Noah', 'Oliver', 'William', 'James', 'Benjamin', 'Lucas', 
        'Henry', 'Alexander', 
        'Mason', 'Michael', 'Ethan', 'Mateo', 'Sebastian', 'Jack', 'Peter', 'Josh', 
        'Patricia', 'Luis', 'Gerardo', 'Carmen'])


    def generar_diccionario_usuarios(self, numero_usuarios : int):
        #Generate a dictionary with random names (keys) and random priority (values) keys : 
        #values
        for i in range(numero_usuarios):
            chosen = self.nombres.pop() # random.choice(self.nombres)
            self.usuarios[chosen] = random.randint(1, 10)
        #DEBUG : Print our users dictionary
        print(self.usuarios)



#Test app
practica = Practica6()
n = 5
print('Usuarios:')
practica.generar_diccionario_usuarios(n)
```

The init always returns an instance of the class.  I think this code above may achieve what you are looking for?  Alternatively it might be good to make a "factory" function to generate many instances of an object with varying properties, rather than have it as a method.  Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, It is another good solution! I complete forgot about the idea of removing the name from the list. Thank you

Comment: @MarioAlmaguer thanks. Using pop on a randomised list was the easiest way I could see to do it.  I thought I was the first answer and then when I posted I was the third or something :D I'm not the fastest typer!